# How do I prevent local users from downloading data from Azure virtual machine to outside

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-nsg

I am building a system in Azure such that the users should not be able to transfer data from Azure virtual machine to outside world. But the administrator should be able to do it.

I am aware that this can be controlled via Azure NSG, but this solution will block ALL users (including  the Administrator account). The virtual machines are not part of Domain, so GPO is out of the question.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to place the data in a Storage account and then make the container as Private and also configure RBAC in such a way that only Admins have access.So, no one from Internet will be able to download.

When you want to download, Admin can generate SAS URL and users can download it.

This is the cost effective and secured way of doing the task.

Comment: We need the virtual machines so that the users can do their work like author and execute python/R scripts etc., We want to limit the local users from downloading data from Azure VM, but only administrator should be able to do it.

Comment: Your ask cannot be done without adding your VM to AD. Or you need to look for any 3rd party solutions.

Comment: Thank you. As an alternative, can we control this via Azure NSG, like open outbound ports when we want to download the data and then close it after downloading the data. (I have marked your answer, since there is no direct solution)